# How to select a class inside the class tag in python with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python re library. No beautifulsoup4 here.

I have:

`<div class="col-xs-12">100/25</div>`

I want:

`<div class="column-md">100/25</div>`

What I need is to select `col-xs-12` ONLY if inside a `<div class="">` and replace it.

So far I have:

`text.replace("<class>(.|\n)col-xs-12<\/class>, "column-md")`

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You should use beautifulsoup. Regular expressions are not adapted to parse html efficiently.

Comment: I don't need to parse html. It's more about find and replace a text file.

Comment: I need to understand something: you mean, in your file you do not have ONLY HTML ? You should use regex only if HTML and plain text are mixed in your file. Otherwise, the most appropriate way to handle this is the Python LibXML library, namely attribute updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `re.sub` with a callback function:

```
def replace_div(m):
    return re.sub(r'\bclass="col-xs-12"', 'class="column-md"', m.group(0))

inp = 'blah <b>stuff</b> blah <div class="col-xs-12">100/25</div> more blah'
out = re.sub(r'<div[^>]*\bclass="col-xs-12"[^>]*>.*?</div>', replace_div, inp)
print(inp)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
blah <b>stuff</b> blah <div class="col-xs-12">100/25</div> more blah
blah <b>stuff</b> blah <div class="column-md">100/25</div> more blah
```

The strategy here is to first match all `<div>` tags containing the appropriate `class` attribute.  Then, we pass such matches to a callback function which then does the class replacement.

Note that in general using regex on nested content like HTML is not recommended.  But, sometimes we are forced to manipulate such content using a text editor.

Comment: Interesting. 1) it doesn't work if there is more than one class (see the comment below plz) 2) Is this the way to extend it to replace other classes `return re.sub(r'\bclass="align-right"', 'class="column-right"', m.group(1))` ?

Comment: 1) It _does_ work if there be more than one class.  The only requirement is that the class you want to target be present.  2) I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: 2) how to extend the function, so I can select more classes.